# How to use 'searchCriteria' and 'fields' in REST API for fetch orders

Tags: sales-order, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I am using below `curl_init` like this,

```
$webSiteUrl = 'mydomain.com'

$last2DayUpdated = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ('-1 day', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))));

$ch = curl_init("{$webSiteUrl}/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={$last2DayUpdated}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq");
```

But I want to fetch particular info like `billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname`

For this, I need to use `fields` parameter.

But both parameters `searchCriteria` and `fields` are not working with each other. Only single parameter is working.

Anyone knows how can I use these both parameters together?

**UPDATED:**

I have tried as below, but not working.

```
$ch = curl_init("{$webSiteUrl}/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={$last2DayUpdated}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&fields=billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need two different filters.

Not same API call but demonstrates how to do it

`/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=size&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=eq`

Although I've also just read online that there was a bug where didn't like this but it's been fixed since

Comment: You gave demo but used only 1 parameter 'searchCriteria', not both. I have updated the question that I am using both parameters but not working. Have you any demo of fetch order as I have explained in a question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html#example-for-search-criteria-to-determine-the-sort-order-and-attributes-to-return):

GET /rest/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=increment_id&
fields=**items[increment_id,entity_id]**

`fields` query parameter requires the `items` key which is array of fields you want to expose.