# REST API: get order entity_id from order increment_id

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order, rest-api

How to get order **`entity_id`** from order **`increment_id`** by **REST API**?

Comment: GET <host>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=0000000001&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your requirements, you have to use order search api point

`http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/orders`

and use GET  and perform the [Search](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html)

```
GET <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/orders/?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={YOURFIELDVALUE}&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks. One query is 'How can I use fields and searchCriteria with API?' Means I need to fetch many orders with minimum fields. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281038/how-to-use-searchcriteria-and-fields-in-rest-api-for-fetch-orders