# How to get get entity_id from order increment_id using REST?

Tags: orders, rest-api

I want to have my `entity_id` of my order, so I can make a deeplink directly to it, from another application. According to this question: [REST API: get order entity_id from order increment_id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281379/rest-api-get-order-entity-id-from-order-increment-id) that should come in the order request from the REST.

However, when I make that call, I do get the entire order completely in my JSON result, *except* for the `entity_id` of the order itself.

How can I make Magento (2.3.7-p2) to return the order `entity_id` using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to checked the same API & its already provided the ENTITY_ID in response.

[image]

Comment: You are right. My bad. I was requesting from the test server, and checking on live.